# What's the best format to use for dates using REST?

Tags: rest, validation, date, language-agnostic

Is there a standard or preferred way to format or enforce a format when I GET/PUT/POST dates/times using a RESTful service?

Is it best to be strict in validation? (e.g., YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS GMT, or a Unix timestamp) Or as a general rule, should date/time formatting be more loosely defined, perhaps with multiple potential formats?

My main concern with Unix timestamps is that they are not very human readable, and I'll have to spend resources converting dates to and from timestamps.

Comment: Unix timestamps are unambiguous and available in most languages.

Comment: @assylias My major concern with Unix timestamps is that they are not very human readable. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Do you need your rest messages to be human readable?

Comment: @assylias I suppose not; but for debugging and logging purposes it feels like it will always take that extra step to interpret a timestamp into something readable.

Comment: If you want to store a humanly-readable time (e.g. logs), consider storing it along with Unix time, not instead of Unix time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO-8601 is generally a portable, readable timestamp format designed with data interchange in mind. It's supported by most languages either natively or through a 3rd-party library.

Unix timestamps, as you say, are not particularly readable and certainly don't make it easy for people to interact with the service - either for exploratory or debug purposes.

One thing to be aware of also is that database support for unix timestamps is not ideal. Natively, MySQL (for example) sees unix timestamps as (simply) unsigned integers. To make use of MySQL date/time manipulation you need to convert that to a MySQL timestamp type. Oracle also, iirc, doesn't really understand a unix timestamp as a date-time type.

For that *kind* of reason, I'd generally use an ISO-8601 format to transfer timestamp information rather than a unix timestamp.